# Why am I getting this dex error [Android Application]?

Tags: java, android

I have no errors (x's) in my project in eclipse yet when I try to run my project I get this error in the console:

[2013-12-29 19:24:30 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/Ad;
[2013-12-29 19:24:30 - AlertCall] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/Ad;

Does anyone know what's wrong?

EDIT: I fixed the problem by doing this: Untick the admob jar file in the "order and export" part of the "configure build path".

Answer (score 1):

Either you have different versions of same *.jar file in your project or different versions of jar file in your reference library & current project.

Replace same jarfile in both reference & current project. Have only one version of *.jar file